# read data from Mongo DB using ODI 12C

Tags: mongodb, oracle-data-integrator

We have a Mongo DB instance hosted on AWS which is being used as a Data Store. The requirement is to read information from a collection within the mongo DB using Oracle Data Integrator 12C hosted on OMCS.

How to connect to Mongo DB using ODI and extract data?

Is any custom code required?

Comment: Hello, did you resolve it?